# Rate of change of eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus

Consider an $n \times n$ matrix $A = A(t)$. Denote its eigenvalues by $\lambda_{i}(t)$ and eigenvectors by $v_{i}(t)$.

I have 2 questions: 
Q1) What is the rate of change of the eigenvalues?
Q2) What is the rate of change of the eigenvectors (expressed in terms of $v_{i}'s$)?

I am thinking of doing something like starting with:
$A(t)v_{i}(t) = \lambda_{i}(t)v_{i}(t)$
Taking derivative,
$\dot{A}v_{i} + A \dot{v_{i}} = \dot{\lambda} v_{i} + \lambda \dot{v_{i}}$
How can I proceed?

Comment: This is hard to answer as is, since there is no canonical choice of eigenvector, so it's not clear what $v_i(t)$ is meant to be. Even if the multiplicity is 1, you can scale an eigenvector by arbitrary nonzero scalars. If your multiplicity is higher, there's a whole high dimensional subspace (minus the origin) of possible choices for $v_i(t)$. Which one are you choosing?

Comment: In the Hermitian case and for the eigenvalues see the Hadamard first variation formula: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/12/254a-notes-3a-eigenvalues-and-sums-of-hermitian-matrices/ Without doing something like normalizing the eigenvectors to have unit length it's not clear that the question for eigenvectors makes sense, and even then in the complex case you have a phase ambiguity to deal with.

Comment: In the case of simple (or semisimple eigenvalues), the eigenvalues will be (locally) differentiable as well as the normalized eigenvectors. However, when the eigenvalues are not semisimple, then the eigenvalues/eigenvectors are not differentiable. You may check the book by Kato, "Perturbation Theory for Linear Operators" and by Seyranian and Mailybaev, "Multiparameter Stability Theory with Mechanical Applications" for more details.